# Host not found (authoritative)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

recently I wrote some app, that create many threads and connect to different servers as client, I used sockets for it, then I realized I can do it with boost library, so I rewrote app to boost part of connections work good and part give this error:

> Host not found (authoritative)

I don't know why it happens, when I used getaddrbyhost it works perfectly but boost resolver give this error...
what can be wrong, every address is domain.

Here is part of code:

```
class client
{
public:
    client(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
           const char* server, const char* port, const int i)
        : resolver_(io_service),
          socket_(io_service),
          i_(i)
    {

        tcp::resolver::query query(tcp::v4(), boost::lexical_cast< std::string >( server ),  boost::lexical_cast< std::string >( port ), boost::asio::ip::resolver_query_base::numeric_service);
        resolver_.async_resolve(query,
                                boost::bind(&client::handle_resolve, this,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                            boost::asio::placeholders::iterator));
    }

private:
    void handle_resolve(const boost::system::error_code& err,
                        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator)
    {
        if (!err)
        {
            boost::asio::async_connect(socket_, endpoint_iterator,
                                       boost::bind(&client::handle_connect, this,
                                                   boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            //here outputs error 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << " Error: " << err.message() << "\n";
        }
    }
```

**edit**
totally weird yesterday I got problems with it and today it works... hmm maybe dhcp was busy or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is host I was trying to connect was outside my LAN network in another LAN network registered as tricky domain. I couldn't know it because I was testing around 20.000~ hosts stored in company database. I thought everything is running at just the one LAN network, but nope.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, the domain is one that is not resolvable by DNS but is resolvable by some other method that the host platform uses, such as an `/etc/hosts` style table, WINS, or some similar name resolution scheme.

Comment: so what can I do, I use linux to test, every domain is global domain not local, it's resolvable by getaddrbyhost but not by boost resolver...

Comment: just for some... but the same domain works with non boost code, it's weird for me

Comment: Is there any pattern to the ones that fail?  Can you share some here?

Comment: Well, the two pieces of code do different things. One uses the host's default name resolution scheme, the other uses DNS. Most likely, the ones that work are ones that resolve through the host's default name resolution scheme but not DNS.

Comment: boost uses dns? it's happens without any pattern, maybe I create too many clients at once, could it be that?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz so what can I do to fix it?

Comment: If you need the platform's domain resolution, you need to call the platform's domain resolution function.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I don't understand, can u explain it ?

Comment: If you want DNS, you can use Boost's DNS resolver. If you want the platform's domain resolution, then you need to call the platform's domain resolution. You need to decide which you need and then call the appropriate function. But you made a *functional* change to your code by using a resolver instead of `getaddrbyhost`.

Comment: I don't know how to fix it, `getaddrbyhost` works good and boost not : / I googled whole internet.